# Office 365 REST API Android Xamarin

Tags: sharepoint, xamarin, xamarin.android, office365

I'm developing an Android app to connect to Office 365 services and be able to upload files to Share Point, using REST API.

I get the AccesToken with this code:

```
public static readonly string DiscoveryServiceResourceId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";
public static string commonAuthority = "https://login.windows.net/common";

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(commonAuthority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(DiscoveryServiceResourceId, clientId, returnUri, new AuthorizationParameters(this));
```

To test I'm doing this first request:

```
var url = "http://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/_api/web/lists";

HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

But I get this response:

```
ex {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x0033b] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00165] in <filename unknown>:0 }  System.Net.WebException
```

Is it a valid GET request?
Do I have to use the AccesToken as I do in the header?
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader());
```

Instead of

`endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);`